# Why does my code not register when I have more then 1 type of module

Tags: java, minecraft

I am making a Minecraft mod that when the user presses a specific button there will be an outcome. My first one was making the user fly. The way I implemented this with the code when the game started was like this:

```
public static void startup()
{
    //Just Prints the Name And version info
    System.out.println("Starting " + Name + " " + Version);
    //Changes Name!
    Display.setTitle(Name +  " v" + Version);
    //Adds all the modules to the actual client base
    modules.add(new CreativeFly());

}
```

The way I detected when the key was pressed and where I held all the info for the modules is like this:

```
package Cupert.Modules;

import Cupert.Modules.Movement.CreativeFly;
import Cupert.Modules.Movement.Sprint;
import Cupert.events.event;
import net.minecraft.client.Minecraft;

//imports
//Setting Up Module structure :)
public class Modules {
    //some variables
    public static boolean toggled;
    public static String name;
    public static int keyCode;
    public static Categories category;
    //THE MINECRAFT VARIABLE
    public Minecraft mc = Minecraft.getMinecraft();
            
    public Modules(String name, int key, Categories c) {
        this.name = name;
        this.keyCode = key; 
        this.category = c;
        
    }
    //check if if Toggled = True
    public boolean IsEnabled() {
        return toggled;
    }
    //getting the key
    public int getKey() {
        return keyCode;
    }
    //toggle function
    public void toggle() {
        toggled = !toggled;
        //enabling and disabling certain functions when either toggled is true or false :D
        if (toggled) {
            onEnable();
        } 
        else {
            onDisable();
        }
    }
    //disable & enable function
    public void onEnable() {
        
    }
    public void onDisable() {
        
    }
    
    //the categories
    public enum Categories {
        COMBAT,
        MOVEMENT,
        PLAYER,
    }

    public void onEvent(event e) {
         
    }
}
```

The way I made the CreativeFly:

```
package Cupert.Modules.Movement;
import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;
import Cupert.Modules.Modules;
import Cupert.events.event;
import Cupert.events.TYPES.Listeners.EventUpdate;
public class CreativeFly extends Modules
{
    //supports the module array in the class modules
public CreativeFly() {
    super("CreativeFly", Keyboard.KEY_G, Categories.MOVEMENT);
    }

//disable & enable function
    public void onEnable()
    {
    mc.thePlayer.capabilities.isFlying = true;  
    mc.thePlayer.capabilities.allowFlying = true;
    
    }
    public void onDisable() 
    {
        mc.thePlayer.capabilities.isFlying = false; 
        mc.thePlayer.capabilities.allowFlying = false;  
    }
    
//checking if is is before or after
     public void onEvent(event e) 
     {
         if(e instanceof EventUpdate) 
         {
             if (e.isPre()) {
                 mc.thePlayer.capabilities.isFlying = true; 
                mc.thePlayer.capabilities.allowFlying = true;
         }
     }
}
}
```

I wanted to add another mod that wasn't CreativeFly so I decided to make a Sprint Mod. The code is here:

```
package Cupert.Modules.Movement;
import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;
import Cupert.Modules.Modules;
import Cupert.events.event;
import Cupert.events.TYPES.Listeners.EventUpdate;
public class Sprint extends Modules
{
    //supports the module array in the class modules
public Sprint() {
    super("Sprint", Keyboard.KEY_N, Categories.MOVEMENT);
    }

//disable & enable function
    public void onEnable()
    {
         mc.thePlayer.setSprinting(true);
    }
    public void onDisable() 
    {
         mc.thePlayer.setSprinting(false);
    }
    
//checking if is is before or after
     public void onEvent(event e) 
     {
         if(e instanceof EventUpdate) 
         {
             if (e.isPre()) {
             mc.thePlayer.setSprinting(true);
         }
     }
}
}
```

But when I add the `Sprint` module to the `StartUp` function in the beginning nothing happens when I press the G key. And when I press the N key rather then sprint I am flying, and it doesn't toggle off for some reason. I don't know what the problem is so I came here hoping someone would answer it.
Bye

Comment: Is there a reason why so many Fields in the Modules class are static?

Comment: Well I thought maybe I might use them in other areas but if that is the reason I will change them back.

Comment: A static variable only exists once per class (Instead of one variable for every instance/object). So all your modules will share one value for "toggled", "name" etc. - Now i don't know much about Minecraft programming but that doesn't seem right at all.

Comment: Thanks, I am still new to java. I changed them and deleted the static.